# Wav analysis in python

Tags: python, wav

I'm looking for a python library that will help me analyze the audio in wav files. At the very least I'm hoping to find some kind of interface that understands .wav format so that I don't have to :P at best I need a module with methods for reading wave form parameters like pitch, volume levels, etc

Answer (score 2):

How about the [wave](http://docs.python.org/library/wave.html) module?